# Filter records from MySQL by year

Tags: mysql

1. If I have column type date and it shows date like this 2013-06-25. How to filter records just by year, e.g. 2011 or 2013?
2. How to filter records that are between dates for example: 2013-06-25 and 2013-07-20

Comment: Probably worth a look [12.7. Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

All dates between 2013-06-25 and 2013-07-20:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE myDateColumn BETWEEN '2013-06-25' AND '2013-07-20'
```

All dates in 2011 or 2013:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE YEAR(myDateColumn) IN (2011, 2013)
```

All dates between 2011 and 2013:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE YEAR(myDateColumn) BETWEEN 2011 AND 2013
```

Or if you have an index on the date and want an optimizable query you should drop the `YEAR` function call:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE myDateColumn BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
```

And have a look at the date functions as suggested. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE date LIKE '%2013%'
```

to get the data that contains the year 2013.

Apply this to your own table structure, and it should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at MySql's [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) which shows you a great deal of information about the different functions available for date and time.  To answer your question, however, I hope that these quick queries will help.

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE datecolumn > '2011-01-01' 
    AND datecolumn < '2012-01-01'
```

Alternatively, you can write this as

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM MyTable 
WHERE datecolumn BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2012-01-01'
```

Writing the queries this way rather than using the `YEAR` function will help take advantage of indexes (if there are any).